# jQuery apply toggleClass to the child element of selector

Tags: jquery

I have a menu item in the format:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

At the moment I am successfully adding a class 'active' to the .sub-menu element show the menu, the problem is my script is showing both the menus when I click one of the a tags, I want the code to show only the child element of what was clicked... Hope this makes sense.. Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
            jQuery('.sub-menu').next().toggleClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` inside the event handler.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!!! Will accept answer in 5 when it allows me! Thanks! xdazz!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class on siblings then add the class to the active menu ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e){
            var $t = $(this);
            $t.siblings().find('.sub-menu').removeClass("active")
             $t.siblings().find('.sub-menu').addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```